# Are ALL keg beer non-pasteurized?

Tags: keg

I understand bottles or cans may or may not be pasteurized. How about Keg beer? I was under the impression that **all** keg beers are not pasteurized because of the volume, is that true? Are there exceptions?

Answer (score 7):

Beer kegged in the USA is usually stored cold and consumed quickly. Therefore, sterile filtration is all that's needed. To make it stable in a wider variety of temperatures, especially shipping it over an ocean, they pasteurize it.

From [Pasteurized Kegged Beer](https://www.micromatic.com/beer-questions/pasteurized-and-non-pasteurized-keg-beer):

> Non-Pasteurized
>
> For the most part keg beer brewed and **packaged in kegs in the U.S**. is
>   not pasteurized. During the packaging process non-pasteurized draft
>   beers are sterile filtered and chilled to the point that any surviving
>   bacteria, which could ferment the beer, become dormant. Kegs are kept
>   cold ( < 50° F ) from the brewery to the point of dispense. Draft beer
>   dispensed from a keg should be fresh by storing as short as possible,
>   and serving cold at 38° F.
>
> Temperatures above 38° F may promote non pasteurized draft beers to
>   turn sour or cloudy. Should the temperature rise above 50° F, the
>   dormant bacteria which ferments and spoils beer will once again become
>   active and, subsequent growth will rapidly begin to spoil flavor and
>   cloud the beer.
>
> Pasteurized
>
> Most of the keg beer brewed and **packaged outside the U.S.** (Import
>   beers), are heat pasteurized during packaging. This process kills off
>   the bacteria that ferment and spoils the beer.
>
> Pasteurized draft beer kegs can be transported and stored at room
>   temperature. The beer in these kegs can be flash cooled at the point
>   of dispense. However, most imported kegs are stored and dispensed at
>   the same temperature (38° F) as domestic, non-pasteurized kegs.